# Unit Test a Scala Lexer

Tags: unit-testing, parsing, scala, parser-combinators

I'm working on an interpreter written using Scala parser combinators. My interpreter separates lexing and parsing into two phases. I'd like to write unit tests for my lexer to ensure it produces correct output.

Right now, I'm unit testing with a helper method method, which I've included below. The method takes the program's source code as a parameter and returns a List of Token objects. Using a unit testing framework (ScalaTest), I can then pattern match against the resulting List of Tokens.

Problems with the current method:

1. It requires a helper method inside of my lexer just to aid unit testing
2. It uses a while loop
3. It resorts to manually constructing and using a Scanner

It seems like there should be a much better way to turn a program's source code into a list of Tokens.

My current working version (the relevant parts, at least):

```
class MyLexer extends StdLexical {
  def lex(input:String): List[Token] = {
    var scanner = new Scanner(input)
    val result = new mutable.ListBuffer[Token]()
    while (!scanner.atEnd) {
      result.append(scanner.first)
      scanner = scanner.rest
    }
    return result.toList
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the helper method should live in the MyLexer class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it isn't very likable. However, wouldn't the following work?

```
// From the unit test
val lexer = new MyLexer
val scanner = new lexer.Scanner(input)
val result = Stream.iterate(scanner)(_.rest).takeWhile(!_.atEnd).map(_.first) // .toList optional
```

Comment: The stream idea is interesting, but invoking `.toList` on the Stream doesn't terminate. Any ideas why?

Comment: @HRJ It obviously isn't receiving anything for which `.atEnd` is true.